# SKAdvisorSettings - no audio playing when Navigation is started

Tags: skmaps

Maybe I'm assuming something, but I thought that the SKAdvisor would "speak" turn by turn navigation. I've run both the demo app, and my own implementation, but neither has made a sound on 3 different devices tested. (Iconia a200, Nexus 7, Galaxy S2)

There are sound files present in mnt/sdcard/....../SKMaps/Maps/Advisor.
I've verified SKAdvisorSettings.getResourcePath() points to the above dir.

Am I supposed to play those files manually when onSignalNewAdvice(..., ...) is triggered?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Right now the code to "play the audio advices" was not added to Android demo (on the iOS demo this code is present). In the next update of the demo project, we'll be adding the required code. Please go ahead and add your own code in onVisualAdviceChanged(), something like: MediaPlayer.play("pathtoyourmp3instruction").

Comment: Thanks Ando. What I actually ended up doing is using the Text to speech engine to handle the OnVisualAdviceChanged.

Here's a little code snippet:

    @Override
    public void onSignalNewAdvice(String[] audioFiles, boolean specialSoundFile) {
         // a new navigation advice was received
     String advice = Arrays.asList(audioFiles).toString().toLowerCase();
     advice = advice.replace("_", " ");
     advice.replace("open", "");
     advice.replace("closed", "");
 mtts.speak(advice, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of the public SDK (ETA 30 June 2014) the code required to play the audio advices will be included in the demo.

For the time being I've attached the required helper files over at: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f4uyk2hm5528mbo/AABchcZjGEgYLTLQxlOv7fDfa

In the demo project, MapActivity.java, replace the code for `onSignalNewAdvice` with:

```
/**
 * new advice has to be played
 * @param audioFiles
 * @param specialSoundFile
 */
@Override
public void onSignalNewAdvice(String[] audioFiles, boolean specialSoundFile) {

    final String selectedLanguageCode = preferences.getStringPreference(PreferenceTypes.K_SELECTED_LANGUAGE_CODE);
    if (!selectedLanguageCode.equals("")) {
        try {
            AdvicePlayer.getInstance().playAdvice(audioFiles, AndroidAudioPlayer.PRIORITY_NAVIGATION);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ando - this looks good. I'll add what I ended up with below.